# Cannot get a textbox value

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have 2 textboxes on an Asp.net(with c#) page and I cannot see this fields from cs class.

In aspx:

```
 <asp:Content ID="BodyContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent">
   <ajaxToolkit:ToolkitScriptManager runat="server"></ajaxToolkit:ToolkitScriptManager>

<div>
<table>
<tr>
   <td style="width:40%"> <asp:Label ID="lblFullname" runat="server" Text="Fullname" ></asp:Label></td>
   <td style="width:20%"> </td>
   <td style="width:40%"> 
       <asp:TextBox ID="txtFullname" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
   <td style="width:40%"> <asp:Label ID="lblBirthDate" runat="server" Text="BirthDate" ></asp:Label></td>
   <td style="width:20%"> </td>
   <td style="width:40%">
      <asp:TextBox ID="txtBirthDate" runat="server" Text="" ></asp:TextBox> 
      <ajaxToolkit:MaskedEditExtender ID="MaskedEditExtenderBirthDate" TargetControlID="txtBirthDate" runat="server" 
      UserDateFormat="DayMonthYear" Mask="99/99/9999" MaskType="Date" ></ajaxToolkit:MaskedEditExtender>
   </td>
</tr>
<tr><td colspan="3" style="float:right"><asp:Button Text ="Save"  runat="server" ID="btnSave" OnClick="btnSave_Click"/> </td></tr>
</table>
</div>
```

And I am trying to get value from the txtFullname.I try txtFullname.Text  and this.txtFullname but the application cannot see this values .
Can somebody how can I get the value for that textbox?

Comment: Show us the code where you are trying to get the value.

Comment: create public properties

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Please check if you have specified the codebehind file name correctly.
>   This could be one of the issues for not getting the control name
>   inside the code file.

If that isn't working for you, please use the below code for reference.

You have not included your "Register" directive. So, I took to privilege to give my own.

Change your markup to:

```
<%@ Page Title="Home Page" Language="vb" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="false"
    CodeBehind="Default.aspx.vb" Inherits="WebApplication2._Default" %> 
   <%@ Register TagPrefix="asp" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" %>
        <asp:Content ID="BodyContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent">
    <asp:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ToolkitScriptManager1" runat="Server" />
    <div>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td style="width: 40%">
                    <asp:Label ID="lblFullname" runat="server" Text="Fullname"></asp:Label>
                </td>
                <td style="width: 20%">
                </td>
                <td style="width: 40%">
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtFullname" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td style="width: 40%">
                    <asp:Label ID="lblBirthDate" runat="server" Text="BirthDate"></asp:Label>
                </td>
                <td style="width: 20%">
                </td>
                <td style="width: 40%">
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtBirthDate" runat="server" Text=""></asp:TextBox>
                    <asp:MaskedEditExtender id="MaskedEditExtenderBirthDate" targetcontrolid="txtBirthDate"
                        runat="server" userdateformat="DayMonthYear" mask="99/99/9999" masktype="Date"></asp:MaskedEditExtender>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="3" style="float: right">
                    <asp:Button Text="Save" runat="server" ID="btnSave" OnClick="btnSave_Click" />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</asp:Content>
```

This code has been tested and is working.

Answer (score 1):

The table tag  is missing runat="server" attribute. Add it in the tag. You should be able to see the fields in cs file

Comment: its not necessary to have runat="server" in table tag.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying in master page or the page file ?  It should work with `runat="server"`

Answer (score 0):

You code is showing that you are using the content page which must use the master page. so you should check following things to resolve this issue.

1. You page must contain the Page directive similar to following one. <%@ Page Title="Home Page" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.master"    AutoEventWireup="true"
   CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>
2. Codebehind file name must be correct like page Default.aspx and Default.aspx.cs
3. You must use runat="server" to make control accessible at server side.